# Can I update rvm without losing my rubies?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I just updated my rvm with

```
rvm get head
```

This command deleted all my rubies in the system. I should do it in my web server, but i don't want to stop my applications for the 10 minutes necessary for the installation.

What can I do to make this update with no pain?

(i'm updating because i need to install ruby 2.0.0, and with older rvm versions it's not available)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating RVM does not delete rubies, you can check what rubies are installed with:

```
rvm list
```

Updating RVM does change the latest patchlevel that is default for ruby so if in earlier version `1.9.3` was pointing out to `1.9.3-p194` it now points to `1.9.3-p429`, if you would like 1.9.3 to point out to `p194` again you can force it with:

```
echo ruby_1.9.3_patch_level=p194 >> $rvm_path/user/db
```

Just remember about it as it will be hardcoding the patchlevel and if you want to update to `p429` you need to remove the line from `$rvm_path/user/db`.

## Important note

The ruby patchlevel is bumped and new version is released when security issues are fixed, no language incompatibilities should be added in patchlevel changes, only fixes for ruby - it should be safe to update ruby patchlevel - and it should be one of the best practices to follow, just use latest patchlevel of ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The lastest rvm stable has ruby-2.0.0 support so just do:

```
rvm get stable
```

that wont delete anything.

Comment: almost ok. The problem now is that my old 1.9.3 is only available as `ruby-1.9.3-p194`. i'd like to rename it back to 1.9.3

Comment: i did this: `rvm alias create 1.9.3 ruby-1.9.3-p194`. Do you think is it ok?